# Insert or update if already exists

Tags: oracle, sql-merge

```
merge into bonuses 
using( select * from bonuses)s ON s.employee_id = '111'   
WHEN MATCHED THEN update set bonus='555' 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN insert insert into BONUSES (employee_id) values(115)
```

Table`s insert queries are

```
insert into BONUSES (employee_id) values(111)
insert into BONUSES (employee_id) values(112)
insert into BONUSES (employee_id) values(113)
insert into BONUSES (employee_id) values(114)
insert into BONUSES (employee_id) values(115)
```

If employee_id=111 already exists it should update else
it should insert.
Kindly help if someone know

Comment: What is the business logic here? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: So if a BONUS record does NOT exist for employee 111 you will add a bonus record for employee 115 ? Weird. If that's correct then you have an interesting bonus regime in the company..

Comment: this is just a sample, if this merge query works I`m gonna implement for other work. Pls help me technically do not look for business logic here..

Comment: It's hard for us to help you if you won't provide requirements we can understand and reason about. I have fixed your syntax errors and showed you how to use MERGE. So what else do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
MERGE INTO bonuses dst
USING ( SELECT '111' AS employee_id, '555' AS bonus FROM DUAL ) src
ON ( dst.employee_id = src.employee_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET bonus = src.bonus
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( employee_id, bonus )
  VALUES ( src.employee_id, src.bonus );
```

Comment: merge query for bonus table that insert data if employee_id not exists else update existing bonus..

Answer (score 1):

Your statement has two syntax errors.

- You have repeated the `insert` keyword.
- You have missed the brackets around the `on` clause conditions. These are mandatory, unlike the join conditions in a normal `from` clause.

So your code should look like this:

```
merge into bonuses b
using( select * from bonuses) s 
ON (s.employee_id = 115)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN update set bonus='555' 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN insert(employee_id) values(115)
/
```

However, it doesn't make sense to have the target table in the `using` clause. It doesn't produce the results you think it's going to...

```
SQL> select * from bonuses;

EMPLOYEE_ID      BONUS
----------- ----------
        111
        112
        113
        114
        115

5 rows selected.

SQL> merge into bonuses b
  2  using( select * from bonuses) s 
  3  ON (s.employee_id = 115)
  4  WHEN MATCHED THEN update set bonus='555' 
  5  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN insert (employee_id) values(115)
  6  /  

9 rows merged.

SQL> select * from bonuses;

EMPLOYEE_ID      BONUS
----------- ----------
        111        555
        112        555
        113        555
        114        555
        115        555
        115
        115
        115
        115

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Maybe something like this would suit you?

```
merge into bonuses b
using( select * from employees) e 
    ON ( b.employee_id = e.employee_id ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    update set bonus= 555 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    insert (employee_id) values (e.id)
```

If you don't have a source of employee IDs distinct from the BONUSES table you can use the DUAL table to fake it:

```
SQL> merge into bonuses b
  2  using( select 115 as employee_id, 555 as bonus from dual union all
  3         select 116 as employee_id, 555 as bonus from dual) e 
  4      ON ( b.employee_id = e.employee_id ) 
  5  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  6      update set bonus= e.bonus 
  7  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  8      insert (employee_id) values (e.employee_id) 
  9  /

2 rows merged.

SQL> select * from bonuses;

EMPLOYEE_ID      BONUS
----------- ----------
        111
        112
        113
        114
        115        555
        116

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: merge query for bonus table that insert data if employee_id not exists else update existing bonus..Any example for this will be helpful, data doesn`t matter

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something like:

```
merge into bonuses tgt
using (select '111' employee_id, '555' bonus from dual) src
  on (tgt.employee_id = src.employee_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  update set tgt.bonus = src.bonus 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  insert (tgt.employee_id, tgt.bonus)
  values (src.employee_id, src.bonus);
```

As an aside, why are you inserting strings into columns which usually have a datatype of some form of NUMBER? Do these columns really have string datatypes (e.g. VARCHAR2, CHAR, etc)?

Comment: merge query for bonus table that insert data if employee_id not exists else update existing bonus..Any example for this will be helpful, data doesn`t matter

Comment: That's what I've provided you with.